# SocketIO VUe app not able to connect to backend getting status 400

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, vue.js, sockets, nginx-ingress

I have a Vue.js application that uses Socket.IO and am able to run it locally but not in a prod setup with S3 and a public socket server. The Vue.js dist/ build is on AWS S3 set up in a public website format. I have DNS and SSL provided by Cloudflare for the S3 bucket.

My socket.io server is running in a Kubernetes cluster that is created using KOPS on AWS. I have a network load balancer in front of it with the ingress being Nginx-ingress. I have added a few annotations as I have been debugging those are at the bottom of the annotations section below.

Error message:

```
WebSocket connection to '<URL>' failed: WebSocket is closed before the connection is established.
```

Issue: I am trying to get my front end to connect to the socket.io server to send messages back and forth. However, I can't due to the above error message. I am looking to figure out what is wrong that is causing this error message.

ingress.yaml

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    # add an annotation indicating the issuer to use.
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
    cert-manager.io/cluster-issuer: "letsencrypt"
    # needed to allow the front end to talk to the back end
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/cors-allow-origin: "https://app.domain.ca"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/cors-allow-credentials: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/enable-cors: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/cors-allow-methods: "GET, PUT, POST, DELETE, PATCH, OPTIONS"
    # needed for monitoring - maybe
    prometheus.io/scrape: "true"
    prometheus.io/port: "10254"
    #for nginx ingress controller
    ad.datadoghq.com/nginx-ingress-controller.check_names: '["nginx","nginx_ingress_controller"]'
    ad.datadoghq.com/nginx-ingress-controller.init_configs: '[{},{}]'
    ad.datadoghq.com/nginx-ingress-controller.instances: '[{"nginx_status_url": "http://%%host%%:18080/nginx_status"},{"prometheus_url": "http://%%host%%:10254/metrics"}]'
    ad.datadoghq.com/nginx-ingress-controller.logs: '[{"service": "controller", "source":"nginx-ingress-controller"}]'
    # Allow websockets to work
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/websocket-services: socketio
    nginx.org/websocket-services: socketio
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-read-timeout: "3600"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-send-timeout: "3600"
  name: socketio-ingress
  namespace: domain
spec:
  rules:
  - host: socket.domain.ca
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: socketio
          servicePort: 9000
        path: /
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - socket.domain.ca
    secretName: socket-ingress-cert
```

socket io part of server.js

```
const server = http.createServer();
const io = require("socket.io")(server, {
  cors: {
    origin: config.CORS_SOCKET, // confirmed this is -- https://app.domain.ca -- via a console.log
  },
  adapter: require("socket.io-redis")({
    pubClient: redisClient,
    subClient: redisClient.duplicate(),
  }),
});
```

vue.js main

```
const socket = io(process.env.VUE_APP_SOCKET_URL)

Vue.use(new VueSocketIO({
  debug: true,
  connection: socket,
  vuex: {
    store,
    actionPrefix: "SOCKET_",
    mutationPrefix: "SOCKET_"
  }
})
);
```